Norm of Riemannian curvature tensor appearing in the context of Kähler-Ricci flow
I am reading an article about Kähler-Ricci flow. I'm stuck at a detail of a proof. The proof states:

Since $|{\rm Rm}(g(t))|\leq\frac ct$, for $s\in(0,t']$, we have
$$\left|\log\frac{\omega^n(s)}{\omega^n(t')}\right|\leq{\rm const.}\log\frac{t'}s,$$
where ${\rm const.}$ is an $n$-dependent factor times $c$.

Generally, there are two different norms in use, the operator norm and the Euclidean norm. The former is defined for a linear map $L:V\to W$ between
normed spaces as
$$|L|:=\sup_{|v|=1}|Lv|.$$
The Euclidean norm is given by
$$|L|=\sqrt{{\rm tr}(V^*\circ V)}.$$
where $L^*:W\to V$ is the adjoint. For example, the Euclidean norm of the Riemannian curvature tensor is
$$\sqrt{g^{\bar\alpha i}g^{\bar j\beta}g^{\bar\gamma k}g^{\bar l\delta}R_{i\bar jk\bar l}\overline{R_{\alpha\bar\beta\gamma\bar\delta}}}.$$

I'm not sure which norm the author's using. My attempt:
$$\left.\log\frac{\omega^n(s)}{\omega^n(t')}=\log\det g(t)\right|_{t'}^s=\int_{t'}^s\frac{(\det g(t))'}{\det g(t)}dt$$
$$=\int_{t'}^sg^{\bar ji}(t)g'_{i\bar j}(t)dt=-2\int_{t'}^sg^{\bar ji}(t)R_{i\bar j}(t)dt.$$
So
$$\left|\log\frac{\omega^n(s)}{\omega^n(t')}\right|\leq2\int_{t'}^s\left|g^{\bar ji}(t)R_{i\bar j}(t)\right|dt=2\int_{t'}^s\left|g^{\bar ji}(t)g^{\bar kl}(t)R_{\bar ki\bar jl}(t)\right|dt.$$
I'm not sure what to do next. Any help would be appreciated!
